# How to refresh all items in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Why does the following code gives me only one row with text "3" after 5 seconds?

```
        var data = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();
        data.Add("foo", new Foo { bar = "1" });

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            listBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(data, null);
            listBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
            listBox.ValueMember = "Key";
        });

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        data["foo"].bar = "3";
        data.Add("bar", new Foo { bar = "2" });

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            listBox.DisplayMember = "";
            listBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
        });
```

How can I display all elements and their changes correctly?

None of the suggested solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615069/how-to-refresh-datasource-of-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-winforms) helped me.

Comment: @Sinatr "What is expected behavior?" -- two lines after 5 seconds ("2" and "3"). "Why you have Sleep in UI thread?" -- for demonstrational purposes. And this is not UI thread

Comment: @Sinatr None of the suggested solutions helped me

Comment: Reassigning datasource works. Do that `listBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(data, null);` in second `Invoke`.

Comment: @Sinatr Yep, thanks a lot