# C# - Update databound combo box automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So I've found a lot of questions similar to this tho nothing really solve my problem..

I have a combobx that is bounded by a datasource

```
cmbProduct.DataSource = this.masterDataSet.Product.Where(x => x.Location == getLocation).AsDataView();
                    cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "Product";
                    cmbProduct.ValueMember = "Product";
```

But whenever i update the source, the combobox items does not update automatically. I still need to close then reopen the form.

is there a method to refresh/reload/or update the combobox?

Comment: The data source would need to be observable and fire off an event (notification) when it was updated. There is already a nice library for this called Reactive Extensions (Rx Extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can use an implementation of [`IBindingList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist(v=vs.110).aspx) as `DataSource` to view changes of data source in the bound list control (complex two-way data binding). The most suitable implementation is [`System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then when you add items to the binding list, or remove item from it you will see changes immediately in the control.

**Solution 2**

But as a more simple solution with less changes for you, you can reset the databinding of your `cmbProduct` this way when you need; for example after a change, call `RefreshBindings();`:

```
public void RefreshBindings()
{
    var list =  put your updated list here;

    this.cmbProduct.DataSource = null;
    this.cmbProduct.DataSource = list;
    this.cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "set the display member here";
    this.cmbProduct.ValueMember = "set the value member here";
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for ur solutions. The second solution does not seem to work, the list only becomes empty and was not populated by the updated list.

I'm new at C# and not really familiar with the binding list.Can u provide a simple sample code for that? Thank you :)

Comment: So I think the second solution is more suitable for you.

Comment: I Copied your code and if your code works, this code should work. for example in my code `getLocation` is not defined and you should change the code a little to make it work. If it shows an empty list it means that the result of query (value of list) is empty. so check the query.

Comment: You can check the edited code and put the values that mentioned in the code.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33625054/3110834) is another of my answers about binding list. Hope you find this and that answer hepful:)

Comment: @Katherine [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) - While you can only accept one answer, you can vote for as many answer as you find helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an event that fires whenever the DataSet changes. The event could reset the Datasource and rebind it.

Somewhere in your code:

`yourDataController.DataChanged += OnDataChanged;`
and the implementation

```
public void OnDataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbProduct.Items.Clear();
    cmbProduct.DataSource = this.masterDataSet.Product.Where(x => x.Location ==     getLocation).AsDataView();
    cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "Product";
    cmbProduct.ValueMember = "Product";
}
```

Edit: Of course you need to manually implement the event and cause it to fire every time your data changes.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur answer. Im not really familiar with DataController, what is it exactly?

Comment: Your data controller is simply your data accessing layer. 
I assume you have some logic that edits or updates your dataset. That is where the event needs to go.