# DataGrid not refreshing in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I got a list of 'word' objects called 'data', I got a function that edits one element in this list and refreshes the DataGridView fine, but when i try to add an item from it and execute a Refresh(), it doesn't add it to the grid.

```
public void edit (string en, string fr, int index)
{
    data[index].english = en;
    data[index].french = fr;
    wordGrid.Refresh();

} // Currently works

private void quickAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fr = addFrenchText.Text;
    string eng = addEnglishText.Text;
    string toWrite = eng + "_" + fr;
    //Adding the word in the current database
    word wordToWrite = new word(toWrite);
    data.Add(wordToWrite);
    wordGrid.Refresh();
} //Doesn't add the occurence
```

Comment: Use a `BindingList<T>` instead of `List<T>`.  Or set `grid.DataSource = null;` then `grid.DataSource = list;` again.

Comment: Thanks ! null to 'data' list worked :D !

Comment: Here is a similar question for `ListBox`: [Connect List<T> to a ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623991/connect-listt-to-a-listbox)

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Please add an answer so I can validate it haha