# Removing an item from a linked list doesn't remove it from a ListBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I linked a list of object to a ListBox control and I want to make the item switch from a ListBox to an another one with the press of a button :

```
ListBox3.DataSource = testsToRunList
ListBox3.DisplayMember = "Name"
ListBox3.ValueMember = "ID"

ListBox4.DataSource = testsToIgnoreList
ListBox4.DisplayMember = "Name"
ListBox4.ValueMember = "ID"
```

...

```
Private Sub SendDownButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SendDownButton.Click
  Dim myobj = ListBox3.SelectedItem

  testsToRunList.Remove(myobj)
  testsToIgnoreList.Add(myobj)

  ' ListBox3.Refresh()
  ' ListBox4.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Changing the item in the linked list doesn't affect the content of the ListBox control. How can I make sure that my ListBoxe's content reflects what is in my linked lists?

Comment: You commented the `ListBox.Refresh()` was it because it wasn't working?

Comment: it's something I tried thinking I had to manually refresh the ListBox, but it didn't have any effect...

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's to your linking your using the `DisplayMember = "Name"` and the `ValueMember = "ID"` so maybe your not removing anything since your not passing the good value. did you try to check what `SelectedItem` returns?

Comment: It returns an object of type Test which is what my lists contain. I can add and remove the object from my list with no problem, but the changes are not reflected on the ListBox even with the DataSource pointing to the list.

Comment: [Connect List<T> to a ListBox and see changes of data source in ListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33623991/3110834)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List(Of T)` class doesn't raise the events required by data-binding to update the control when the list is modified. Either bind via a BindingSource and call the appropriate method to reset the bound control or use a `BindingList(Of T)` instead.