# Modifying original DataSource doesn't update ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ComboBox` with a `DataSource` set to application settings as follows

```
public DetailsForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.comboBox1.DataSource = TextSelectionSettings.Default.categories;
}
```

But I want users to add extra items to the combo box if they need to at runtime. So I just made a simple click event on a textbox to test adding a new string to the list.

```
private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextSelectionSettings.Default.categories.Add("test");
    TextSelectionSettings.Default.Save();
}
```

However the `ComboBox` doesn't show the new string I added to the settings.

How can I refresh the `ComboBox` to show the changes in the settings?

- `Refresh()` function on the combo box did not work.
- setting the `DataSource` again did not work either.
- I cannot add the `Item` directly to `ComboBox` using `Items.Add()` method because the `DataSource` is set.

Comment: In order for it to pick up on the change it must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Try setting the `DataSource = null` and then set it again.

Comment: @RonBeyer setting DataSource to null and then back again to the categories worked, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625054/3110834

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for the Data Bindings in Windows Forms (and WPF) to work, it has to have some kind of change-notification like `IBindingList` or `INotifyCollectionChanged` to be able to notice the changes.

- Calling `Refresh()` is simply for painting and doesn't refresh the bindings
- Setting the `.DataSource` to the same thing won't work (you don't change anything, so it doesn't notice it as a change)

The work-around is to set the `.DataSource` to `null` and then set it back to the collection again. This causes it to re-evaluate the binding (because it is a different object than the current `null` one) and reset your values.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is completely irrelevant to the problem. Relevant interface for this problem (receiving `ListChanged` notifications) is `IBindingLust` as described in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625054/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei I removed it, although for other Data bindings `INotifyPropertyChanged` would be relevant to data binding (things like Textbox), but yes, not relevant in this scenario.