# Append clipboard text to a listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, listbox

So I created a variable to hold my clipboard text and I have no idea on how to append it to a listbox.

This is as far as I got..

```
private void clipboardBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string items = Clipboard.GetText();
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();
    _items.AddRange(items);
}
```

but that throws me this error..

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

What's causing this and how do I fix it? Is this even the correct way of appending text to the listbox?

-UPDATE-

I got this now but everytime I click the button it overwrites the old one instead of appending a new item to the listbox

```
    string items = Clipboard.GetText();
    List<string> _items = new List<string>();
    _items.Add(items);
    listBox1.DataSource =_items;
```

How do i append a new item?

Comment: look at my updated answer maybe it will help

Answer (score 1):

[`Clipboard.GetText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz40084e(v=vs.110).aspx) has the signature

```
public static string GetText()
```

but [`List<T>.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) has the signature

```
public void AddRange( IEnumerable<T> collection )
```

So essentially you're trying to add a `string` as an `IEnumerable<T>` which gives you the above error.

Better use [`List<T>.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx) for that purpose like that:

```
_items.Add(items);
```

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @JonnyKhanas: Does [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17615338/1305969) help you?

Answer (score 0):

your question is about `List` object and not about `ListBox` control. 
 
the `AddRange()` method requires a collection, you can transform your string to a collection (Array) by using `Split`.

```
private void clipboardBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string YourGetClipBoardTextString = "aaa;bbb;ccc;ddd";
            List<string> _items = new List<string>();
            _items.AddRange(YourGetClipBoardTextString.Split(';').ToArray()); // you can split the string by any char seperator ";" " ", "," etc...
}
```

if you dont need to split the string just use the Add() method:

```
_items.Add(YourGetClipBoardTextString);
```

**After your update**, you can append new items to a listbox in that manner:

```
    foreach (string itm in _items)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(itm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're creating new "_items" on every click, you cannot see the old items. try like this,

```
 List<string> _items = new List<string>();
    private void clipboardBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string items = Clipboard.GetText();
        _items.Add(items);
        listBox1.DataSource =_items;
    }
```

_items declared outside of method scope.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split the clipboard contents into strings for each line, then you need to add them to the list box:

```
string[] items = Clipboard.GetText().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
```

If you don't want to have a separate listBox item for each line, just do this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(Clipboard.GetText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are initializing a new list each time:

```
string items = Clipboard.GetText();
List<string> _items = new List<string>();//<New list here results in removal of existing item
_items.Add(items);
listBox1.DataSource =_items;
```

Try something like this:

```
 string items = Clipboard.GetText();
List<string> _items = listBox1.DataSource as List<string>;// You may have type casting issues here - 
_items.Add(items);
listBox1.DataSource =_items;
```