# C# Button not firing more than once

Tags: c#, button

When I click the button the first time, it works, but after that, it doesn't do anything. I have tried to debug this and I have looked it up but I can't find an answer. I am probably just not noticing something obvious.

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] files;

        files = Directory.GetFiles("Tasks");

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string[] lines;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
            tasks.Add(lines[0]);
            reader.Close();
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = tasks;
    }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Thank you for the advice, I will try it. Thanks about the `reader` lines as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is not with the button. It's with the listbox. It's not updating properly because it's not detecting a change in your datasource.

Try setting it to null before updating so it knows it's changing:

```
listBox1.DataSource = null;
listBox1.DataSource = tasks;
```

**Alternative Method:**

You can also use a BindingList instead of a regular list.

See here:
[How to refresh DataSource of a ListBox in C# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615069/how-to-refresh-datasource-of-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-winforms)