# Why is my listbox not showing more than one item?

Tags: c#

This seems pretty simple, and I'm not sure why its not working.

I have a button that when clicked adds an item to a list in the class:form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<string> photoNames = new List<string>();


    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Hunce1947@superrito.com
        photoNames.Add("Ree");
        listBox1.DataSource = photoNames;
    }
```

However, whenever you click the item only a single item shows up. Why are multiple instances of "Ree" not showing up?

Comment: What's `photoNames` object declare?

Comment: Thats the list. List<string> photoNames = new List<string>();

Comment: how many elements are there in your list ? Show us more code to determine the problem.

Comment: Sorry guys but this is all the code thats being used.

Comment: @Hunce1947 use the debugger.  Check how many items are in `photoNames` every time you click.

Comment: I think this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615069/how-to-refresh-datasource-of-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh DataSource of a ListBox in C# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615069/how-to-refresh-datasource-of-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Answer (score 0):

Listbox don't detect the changes in the datasource. So set DataSource to null 
first, then reassign datasource again.
This will work for you.

```
List<string> photoNames = new List<string>();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    photoNames.Add("Ree");
    listBox1.DataSource = null;
    listBox1.DataSource = photoNames;                
}
```

Comment: How would this help?  OP already sets the DataSource to `photoNames` _after_ they modified `photoNames`...

Comment: @maccettura Well, as I explained, the listbox not catching the changes, you could run the code to see what results you'll get :)

Comment: Setting listBox1.DataSource = null also sets DisplayMember to the empty string (but not ValueMember)...  This could be confusing

Comment: @maccettura Why not ValueMember ? would you explain a little ?

Comment: just the way it is.  Its better to use a `BindingList<T>` instead of setting the datasource to null

Comment: It'll be useful for sure with `ListChanged` as there is an event for listBox.DataSourceChanged, but I took the shortest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment but I believe photoNames is a dataset, in that case I would say you you create a datatable and add rows.

```
 DataSet photoNames = new DataSet();

 DataTable dt = new DataTable("photoName");
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pname", typeof(string)));

 ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

and then instead of doing

```
photoNames.Add("Ree");
```

you can add ree as a row in the table of that dataset and bind it to your listbox like this:

```
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["photoName"] = "Ree";
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 listBox1.DataSource = photoNames;
```

Comment: Do you really need DataTable and DataSet to do that ? What a waste of resources. !

Comment: @Kaj As at when this question was posted, it was not specified that photoNames was a list. I dont have enough reputation to ask in the comment (read my answer) it was sorta safe to assume that it was a dataset as that's not completely out of context